# tail: cannot open ''$'\033''[35m/home/test/yr9.log'$'\033''[39m' for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell

I ran a "forever list" command in a Linux terminal and the command returns the following output

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command       script             forever pid  id logfile                          uptime
data:    [0] yr9 /usr/bin/node /home/test/index.js 1370    1377    /home/test/yr9.log 6:9:17:4.829000000027008
```

Here I want to extract only the "logfile" path that is "/home/test/yr9.log" using the below command

```
path=$(forever list | cut -d' '  -f17 | sed '/^$/d')
```

and I stored the path in a variable.

Now I want to take only the last line from the log file and I tried the below command

```
last=$(tail -1 "$path")
```

But it throws the below error

```
tail: cannot open ''$'\033''[35m/home/trnd2020/.forever/_yr9.log'$'\033''[39m' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: You have content with ANSI sequences

Comment: Yes, when I saved the output to a file it looks like below
```
  GNU nano 2.9.3                                                                             list.txt

^[[32minfo^[[39m:    Forever processes running
^[[90mdata^[[39m:    ^[[37m   ^[[39m ^[[37muid^[[39m  ^[[90mcommand^[[39m       ^[[90mscript^[[39m                                                         ^[[37mforever^[[39m ^[[37mpid^[[3$
^[[90mdata^[[39m:    [0] _yr9 ^[[90m/usr/bin/node^[[39m ^[[90m/home/test/index.js^[[39m 1370    1377    ^[[35m/home/test/_yr9.log^[[```

Answer (score 0):

Your forever command returns some style options terminal style (text coloration and more). Did you try with `export TERM=xterm-mono` before running command ?

Maybe you should try with `forever logs` if you're using https://github.com/foreversd/forever ?

Comment: I tried "export TERM=xterm-mono" now but still the same issue. The log file is in the "purple" color.

Comment: You have to disable color by any way

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by "Remove color codes (special characters) with sed"
`sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"`

Expected command:
`path=$(forever list | cut -d' '  -f17 | sed '/^$/d' | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g")`

Answer (score 0):

"Forever" decorate output on CLI.
In order to make Command Line output colorful.. "Forever" uses ANSI color.
As explained on https://github.com/foreversd/forever.
Use below options according to your requirements.

> --colors         To color output and --no-colors will disable output coloring

> --plain          Disable command line colors

Below code worked well for me while making shell script to print forever processes logs

```
myarr=($(forever logs --plain | tail -n +3 | awk '{printf "%s\n",$4}'))
for f in "${myarr[@]}"
do
   :
  echo "$f"
  tail -n 100 $f # You can use.. cat $f
done
```